# Is it possible to make a evenly split Accordion view(Expandable view) in Android?

Tags: android, accordion, expandablelistview

I'm trying to make 3 evenly split Expandable menu.
I've been working this for over a week. but it seems impossible to create it.

The layout effect I want to make is like this.

let's say 300dp is my device height.
and there are 3headers(50dp each) and 3 expandable layouts.
it will be a static accordion menu so, scrollbar is not necessary.

if the user click one of the items.
it should be expanded as 200dp.(300dp - 50dp*2)
And the other 2 expandable items should shrink into 0dp.

expand/collapse has animations, and animations should have a specific value according to the Android `Animator` class. But if I want to animate two layouts simultaneously it causes the calculation problem.

I tried 2 Github libs so far.

- https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout
- https://github.com/florent37/ExpansionPanel

But, the both have sample problems. Please refer to my representations.

- representation video1 : https://youtu.be/yJ7ZIQWG3no
- representation video2 : https://youtu.be/xQ8HoWWdPOU
- representation video3 : https://youtu.be/kO4cfYp36Co

Also, I posted this question as an issue here : https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout/issues/78
You can see the layout file here but one of the contributors said, it's not the problem of the library. but about animation or size calculation.

What I've tried so far:

- LinearLayout as a root layout and each headers have `android:layout_weight="1"` attrs.
- Constraitlayout and each headers have `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.33"`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an alternative UI library called stepper.
- https://github.com/fython/MaterialStepperView